# How validate complex objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

Can you tell how you validate complex objects with big nesting ? For example I have product, options and variants. Product relate with options, options relate with choices. And for update product I send big object that need to validate, not only for types, but for existing option id, variant id, that particular choice relate to particular option and so forth, and if it don't exist throw error, each entity is inside an array.

Object example:

```
{
    'id': 3,
    'price': '3767.07',
    'name': 'pizza',
    'url': 'product1',
    'options': [
      {
        'id': 5,
        'name': 'size',
        'type': 'SELECT',
        'defaultChoice': 0,
        'required': false,
        'choices': [
          {
            'id': 1,
            'text': 'M',
            'price': 2923.27,
            'modifierType': 'ABSOLUTE',
            'modifierVariant': '+',
          },
          {
            'id': 8
            'text': 'L',
            'price': 1826.03,
            'modifierType': 'ABSOLUTE',
            'modifierVariant': '-',
          },
        ],
      }
```

Comment: There are a lot of libraries for writing assertions out there ....

Comment: In 2 parts - 1) Parse the "complex object" and pull out simple objects 2) Validate simple objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different libraries that you can use for that, for example the following.

- [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi)
- [superstruct](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/superstruct)
- [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup)
- [runtypes](https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes)
- [v8n](https://github.com/imbrn/v8n)
- [whitelister](https://github.com/SpireTeam/whitelister)

In addition, it is also reasonably easy to create something by yourself. You can have a look at those libraries' documentations and source code for inspiration.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment.